# change anchor tag href thats loaded through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Basically I have a gridview that I page through the server instead of in memory, the problem is every row in the gridview has a url that I change with javascript, The server control I am using for this colum in the asp:HyperLinkField. The reason this must be done in javascript dynamic is because I must escape the parameter that is appended to url as a query parameter because it could have hash tags in them.So my javascript:

```
$('#<%=grid1.ClientID%> a').each( function(){
 var url=   $(this).attr("href");
    var parameter =//this line gets the parameter from the url
  url= "Page.aspx?param="+escape(parameter);
  $(this).attr("href", url);
});
```

This works on first page load with the urls that are initally stored in the gridview, but since I am doing paging on the server and using ajax(asp.net updatepanel) as well, so the next page doesnt have the javascript fired since it doesn't refresh the page. I think jquery live would come into play here, but not sure if thats accurate because I think a event has to be triggered in order to initiate the live handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately `live` handlers won't work for changing the actual href. However, if you change your approach somewhat, you can get the same effect.

```
$('#<%=grid1.ClientID%> a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var parameter =//this line gets the parameter from the url
    url = "Page.aspx?param="+escape(parameter);
    window.location = url;
});
```

So rather than changing the actual attribute on each link, you override the behavior associated with clicking that link.

Comment: that approach works, just one change,since I am using IE e.preventDefault() has to be replaced with e.returnValue=false

Comment: @Jake: Are you sure? `e.preventDefault()` is a jQuery function that ought to be compatible across all browsers.

Comment: @Jake: That page doesn't even mention jQuery. jQuery takes care of translating `.preventDefault()` into whatever is required by the current browser. Try this example using Internet Explorer: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQMfj/3/

Comment: maybe i forgot to add the e in function parameters, but since returnvalue =false works, I dont see a reason to change it.. thanks though

Comment: @Jake: As long as all your users will only ever use IE, that's fine.

Comment: I just tried e.preventDefault() again and it reutrns error "object doesn't support this action" ie7

Comment: @Jake: I suspect you forgot to declare `e` as a function parameter. This shows an example of someone running into the same issue: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/event-preventdefault-and-ie

Comment: Nope I have the e passed, thats how my e.returnValue= false works